# how to install new download of 14.04.1-desktop-amd 64.ISO

Tags: system-installation, ati, downloads, helpfile

I have no idea what I am doing here. I was given an IBM ThinkPad with an outdated Ubuntu OS and could not figure out how to upgrade, so I simply downloaded the new 14.04.1-desktop-amd 64 ISO. The download completed. There is an icon on the desktop. But being a PC user for all my computer life... I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install this OS! Can anyone help me?

Comment: first of all do you have any os preinstalled on it

Comment: Before you install Ubuntu, please check your IBM ThinkPad's hardware and compare it with the results in the answers to [How to know which Ubuntu is right for my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-to-know-which-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware) and also check if your CPU supports the amd64 architecture. If your CPU is a Pentium 4, you can only install the 32-bit iso file. Check your CPU's operating modes (aka instruction set) in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Windows shouldn't be a problem for installing an OS.  This installation is no different than installing a Windows ISO OS.  It's exactly the same.

Just burn the ISO to a disk, boot to it, and follow the prompts.

The installation questions in Ubuntu should even be easier.  It basically asks for a user name and password, perform the installation and reboots into the OS.

Upgrading should be just as easy.  The command to upgrade is:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Then follow the prompts.  The upgrade is different from Windows upgrade.  I don't think Windows has an equivalent.  It certainly doesn't have this simplicity.  But of course, this being different is a command that you would have had to be provided with to know it.

The system would normally advise you of this command periodically when there is an upgrade available.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:
Download 32-bit non-pae Xubuntu 12.04.5:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/precise/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-i386.iso
Just burn the ISO to a disk or usb:
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/u/unetbootin/unetbootin_603-1_i386.deb
Boot to it, and follow the prompts.